# Email signature handling in exchange online

Tags: node.js, email, cloud, exchange-server, signature

Is there an existing api or any way to create, change and delete signatures in the cloud for outlook? We're using exchange online as our cloud solution and need to manage them from a node js application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EWS (ExchangeWebService) exposes ways to get/set user's signature.
I haven't used it but you should take a look at Node-Ews which is a wrapper for EWS API.